# Convert RGB image to YUV and YCbCr color space image in Opencv Python

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, image-preprocessing

Can anyone help me to convert an RGB colour space image to YUV colour space image and to YCbCr colour space image using opencv Python?

Comment: cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `cv2.cvtColor(src, code)` to convert Color-Space, the code starts with `COLOR_`.

You can use this to look for the color code.

```
import cv2
## get all color codes
codes = [x for x in dir(cv2) if x.startswith("COLOR_")]

## print first three color codes
print(codes[:3])
# ['COLOR_BAYER_BG2BGR', 'COLOR_BAYER_BG2BGRA', 'COLOR_BAYER_BG2BGR_EA']

## print all color codes
print(codes)
```

If you read the image into `BGR` space, then use `cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV` and `cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb`:

```
#cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV
#cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb

img = cv2.imread("test.png")
yuv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV)
cv2.imwrite("yuv.png", yuv)
```

If you read the image into `RGB` space, then use `cv2.COLOR_RGB2YUV` and `cv2.COLOR_RGB2YCrCb`.

---

Here is an example image(in BGR-HSV-YUV-YCRCB color spaces):

[image]

Comment: Note that `cv2.COLOR_RGB2YCrCb` produces a 3D array, while reslut of `cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV_YV12` is a 2D array with same height (`im.shape[0] == h`), but extra width (`im.shape[1] == w*3/2`), and *chroma* info (**U** and **V**) are stored there interlaced. Also, the numerical values are different for YUV and YCrCb: for the former, *luminance* is between **16** to **235**, as expected for [some video gamuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rec._709), while YCrCb is full **0..255** range.

Comment: @AlexCohn Instead of  cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV_YV12 is there a conversion code for YCrCb 420 format? I couldn't find it in the documentation

Comment: @ShravyaBoggarapu I am not sure I understand your question. What is your input format, and what do you need on output?

Comment: @AlexCohn, YUV uses only video range (16-235) but YCrCb uses the full pixel range, right? but it is always present in 444 format (1: 1: 1 for the 3 components) but 420 format is such that the chroma components are quarter the size of luma component. OpenCV provides means to convert to YUV420 (video range) but not full range- as far as I could find. I was wondering if you knew