# FFMpeg vs. OpenCV for format conversion/simple transformation

Tags: c++, performance, opencv, ffmpeg, vision

I had to create a system that can process images in realtime. I have implemented in C++ a pixel format conversion system that can also do some simple transformation (currently: rotation & mirroring).

Input/output format of the system are frame in a the following formats:

- RGB (24, 32)
- YUYV420, YUYV 422
- JPEG
- Raw greyscale

For instance, one operation can be:

- YUYV422 -> rotation 90 -> flip Horiz -> RGB24
- Greyscale -> rotation 270 -> flip Vert -> YUYV420

The goal of the system is to offer best performance for rotation/mirroring and pixel format conversion. My current implementation rely on OpenCV, but I suffer from performance issues when processing data above 2k resolutions.

The current implementation uses cv::Mat and cv::transpose/cv::flip/cv::cvtColor, and I optimized the system to remove transitionnal buffers and copy as much as possible.

Not very happy to reinvent the wheel, I know that using swscale and some filters from FFMpeg, it is possible to achieve the same result. My question are:

1. The FFMpeg system is rather generic, do you think I might suffer from footprint/performance caveat with this solution?
2. Format conversion seems somewhat ooptimized in OpenCV, but I have no idea about FFMpeg implementation... (note: I'm on x86_64 intel platform with SSE)
3. Do you know any library than can handle this kind of simple transformation for real time?

Thank you

Comment: 2k is huge. Is there enough room for enhancement in the hardware setup ? (I/O bandwidth, etc.)

Comment: OpenCV can use FFMpeg as its background: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/da7/videoio_overview.html
What do you mean by realtime? How many fps do you want to achieve? As @9dan spotted- there may be hardware limitations.

Comment: @9dan what do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV implementation is optimised for your configuration. Don't expect improvements from ffmpeg. Recently, OpenCV switched to libjpeg-turbo <s>with SSE optimizations</s>, this may improve JPEG conversions.

Comment: It is `libjpeg-turbo` but without SIMD that is included for now (see [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/12115)). Feel free to submit a pull request to add SIMD support.

Comment: @Catree thanks for this clarification. I understand that this concerns the official release, local build can enable SIMD easily, can't it?

Comment: `libjpeg-turbo` included as a third-party into OpenCV does not have SIMD code. Yes you should be able to install `libjpeg-turbo` (e.g. from a package manager) and OpenCV should be able to automatically detect and link against the host `libjpeg-turbo`.

Comment: Hi Alex, do you have some resource/numbers/link to give forr this assessment? Is it your personnal experience? Thx

Comment: No, I don't have strict measurements at hand. My experience with ffmpeg in similar transformations was rather disappointing. If you find a confirmation or a contradictory evidence, please post it here.

Comment: OpenCV is really poor when trying to convert from **other format** to YUV (e.g: impossible to convert RGB(A) to YUV420 for instance)

Comment: @lp35 please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/48125183/192373 if you have some troubles with this